# Скачивание файла с помощью js / jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Есть обычная ссылка:

```
<a href="#">Ссылка</a>
```

Задача следующая:

1. Пользователь щелкает по ссылке, нажатие не обрабатывается (возможно event.preventDefault();)
2. Происходит выбор некоего условия, где определяется href атрибут ссылки и подставляется в тег
3. Происходит переход по ссылке с новым href атрибутом.

Нужно чтобы скачивался CSV файл по аналогии с атрибутом атрибутом "download":

```
 <a href="/my.pdf" download="MyPDFReport">Скачать PDF</a>
```

Возможно есть более простые методы решения вопроса?

Comment: ага, можно в тег не подставлять, а сразу переход делать что нить типа window.location.href="/my.pdf"

Comment: Пробовал. В хроме csv файл открывается сразу в браузере.

Comment: https://github.com/PixelsCommander/Download-File-JS

Comment: Годится, спасибо. Может кому пригодится еще не JS способ - правка .htaccess

 AddType application/octet-stream .csv